# Detecting numbers pattern in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I have bunch of images which they have similar number pattern. I'm going to detect only number in specific part of my papers by python OpenCV then start OCR numbers

I can crop corner of image but there is too much words around that number, all numbers have specific pattern ( 16 digits )

there is no rectangle border around numbers like car License Plate which can help me to detect contours around numbers

[image]
[image]

- How can I just detect and crop around numbers?
- How can I draw contour around numbers?
- Is there any classification method to do that?

Comment: I don't see any 16-digit numbers in your image? It is important that your image is properly representative in content, quality and format if you want a decent answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: those pictures are as an example , My papers are in Persian language and there is difference between Persian and English language
I just want to detect those numbers and crop them , I will add an image with specific pattern (16 digits)

Comment: Can you post your code? So we can help you.